# Cannot reproduce query param html injection

Tags: javascript, xss, query-string

We have an embedded script running on the page of one our clients. We received a report from them that the query params we send to that page are not properly guarded against XSS injection.

When I try a url like:
`https://www.clientsite.com?somekey=%3Csvg%20onload%3Dalert(document.cookie)%3E`

on their site, I indeed get the alert panel displaying the cookies.

But when I run our script locally, I cannot reproduce this injection. The alert panel never shows up, no matter what I put in the query param's value.

A very simplified version of the script is:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>XSS test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <script>
   (function() {
    var url = window.location.href
    var someKey = 'somekey'
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+someKey+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(url);

    var parentElement = document.querySelector('#content');
    var widget = document.createElement('div');
    // var svgInjection = '<svg onload=alert("alert!!")>'
    // var svgEncodedInjection = '%3Csvg%20onload%3Dalert("alert!!")%3E'
    widget.innerHTML = '<div>' + results[1] + '</div>';

    return parentElement.insertBefore(widget, parentElement.firstChild);
   })()
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand how an identical script, receiving identical query params, shows an alert panel on the client's site, and nothing when I run it locally. Any thoughts?

Comment: the code you posted is safe, you would need to use `widget.innerHTML =  decodeURIComponent(results[1])` for it to work/inject else it will be encoded, are you sure the client's code is not doing that or, using that get param server-side and placing it on the page without doing entitiy encoding on it?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, the clients page is very full, all sorts of things going on. Is there any way I can find out wether they are parsing the params somewhere? In the console, when I do `window.location.href`, the param is like this: `%3Csvg%20onload%3Dalert(document.cookie)%3E`, so basically the same as the input. But I am not sure what to make of that.